# Module not found with npm package in React app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, protocol-buffers

I have a React app that takes some data from an API. The data is transit data and is serialized with protocol buffers, so I'm using the gtfs-realtime-bindings.js package to deserialize it. That also uses ProtoBuf.js and ByteBuffer.js under the hood. However, when I run my dev server, I'm getting this error in the browser:

```
./node_modules/protobufjs/ProtoBuf.js
Module not found: `/Users/Ben/React/subway-
checker/node_modules/ByteBuffer/ByteBuffer.js` does not match the 
corresponding path on disk `bytebuffer`.
```

I'm not really sure how to start debugging this. It could be a Webpack issue? I'm using create-react-app if that helps diagnose.

For context, here's the rest of the code in the file that's causing the error:

import GtfsRealtimeBindings from 'gtfs-realtime-bindings';
    import request from 'request';

```
function getFeedData (sub) {
    var feedId;
    switch (sub) {
        case '1' || '2' || '3' || '4' || '5' || '6' || 'S':
                feedId = 1;
                break;
            case 'A' || 'C' || 'E':
                feedId = 26;
                break;
            case 'N' || 'Q' || 'R' || 'W':
                feedId = 16;
                break;
            case 'B' || 'D' || 'F' || 'M':
                feedId = 21;
                break;
            case 'L':
                feedId = 2;
                break;
            case 'G':
                feedId = 31;
                break;
    }
    var requestSettings = {
      method: 'GET',
      uri: 'http://datamine.mta.info/mta_esi.php?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE&feed_id=2',
      encoding: null
    };
    request(requestSettings, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
          var feed = GtfsRealtimeBindings.FeedMessage.decode(body);
          return { feed: feed };
        }
    });
}

function reverseStop (sub, stop) {
    var stopIdN
    var stopIdS
    var stopData = require('./stops');
    var invalidEntries = 0;
    function filterByName (item) {
        if (item.stop_name == stop && item.stop_id.charAt(0) == sub) {
            return true;
        }
        invalidEntries++;
        return false;
    }
    var stopObjs = stopData.filter(filterByName);
    for (var i = 0; i < stopObjs.length; i++) {
        if (stopObjs[i].stop_id.charAt(stopObjs[i].stop_id.length - 1) == 'N') {
            stopIdN = stopObjs[i].stop_id;
        } else if (stopObjs[i].stop_id.charAt(stopObjs[i].stop_id.length - 1) == 'S') {
            stopIdS = stopObjs[i].stop_id;
        }
    }
    return {
        stopIdN: stopIdN,
        stopIdS: stopIdS
    };
}

var isDelayN = (function (sub, stop) {
    var arrivals = [];
    var delays = [];
    reverseStop(sub, stop);
    getFeedData(sub);
    (function () {
            var invalidEntries = 0;
            var feedObjs = getFeedData.feed.filter(function (feedObj) {
                if (feedObj.entity.trip_update.stop_time_update.stop_id == reverseStop.stopIdN) {
                    return feedObj.entity.trip_update.stop_time_update;
                }
            });
            for (var i = 0; i < feedObjs.length; i++) {
                arrivals.push(feedObjs.arrival.time.low);
                delays.push(feedObjs.arrival.delay);
            }
        })();
    var nextArrival = Math.min(...arrivals);
    var delayIndex = arrivals.findIndexOf(nextArrival);
    var delay = delays.delayIndex;
    if (delay === null || Math.ceil(delay / 60) <= 5) {
        var noDelay = Math.ceil((nextArrival - getFeedData.feed.header.timestamp.low) / 60);
        return { noDelay: noDelay };
    } else {
        var yesDelay = Math.ceil(delay / 60);
        return { yesDelay: yesDelay };
    }
})();

var isDelayS = (function (sub, stop) {
    var arrivals = [];
    var delays = [];
    reverseStop(stop);
    getFeedData(sub)
        .then(function (feed) {
            var invalidEntries = 0;
            var feedObjs = feed.filter(function (feedObj) {
                if (feedObj.entity.trip_update.stop_time_update.stop_id == reverseStop.stopIdS) {
                    return feedObj.entity.trip_update.stop_time_update;
                }
            });
            for (var i = 0; i < feedObjs; i++) {
                arrivals.push(feedObjs.arrival.time.low);
                delays.push(feedObjs.arrival.delay);
            }
        });
    var nextArrival = Math.min(...arrivals);
    var delayInex = arrivals.findIndexOf(nextArrival);
    var delay = delays.delayIndex;
    if (delay === null || Math.ceil(delay / 60) <= 5) {
        var noDelay = Math.ceil((nextArrival - getFeedData.feed.header.timestamp.low) / 60);
        return { noDelay: noDelay };
    } else {
        var yesDelay = Math.ceil(delay / 60);
        return { yesDelay: yesDelay };
    }
})();

export { isDelayN, isDelayS };
```

I realize that code may need a lot of context. In lieu of posting all of my components and having an unreasonably long post, here's the full Github repo as it stands right now: https://github.com/benuchadnezzar/subway-checker

Any help is appreciated! Including if you see something else egregiously wrong with the code in this file.

Comment: Weird. Judging be the error message it looks like an case issue. Did you check the `ByteBuffer` folder in `node_modules` and verify that it is camel cased? Or that it exists at all?

Comment: @RickJolly So I just checked on that. The folder in `node_modules` was not camel cased. I changed it to be camel cased and restarted my server, but I'm still getting that same error.